# Swift - Selected tab bar index not triggering scroll to top

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar with five items, and I am trying to add a functionality to scroll to the top when the user taps the tab bar item again. Added the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to the views where I want to trigger the event and also created a function to determine the selected tab bar index.

When I open the app, index 0 is auto-selected and works perfectly. The view auto scrolls to the top when I scroll down and tap the tab bar index. The problem occurs when I go to index 1 and trigger the scroll there. It somehow completely removes the auto-scroll from my first tab bar item.

Selecting other tab bar items without the auto scroll does not affect index 0 at all.

**Home (index 0)**

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
    if tabBarIndex == 0 {
        self.collectionView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -10), animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Users (index 1)**

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
    if tabBarIndex == 1 {
        self.tableView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: A `UITabBarController` can only have one delegate. The last one wins.

Comment: Really! Well, how can I add the auto scroll to two different tab bar items, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything with a `delegate` property can only have one delegate assigned to it at any given time. What ever set the `delegate` most recently will receive the next delegate method call.

In your case you can probably reset the tab controller's `delegate` to `self` in each view controller's `viewDidAppear` method since you want the currently visible view controller to be the current tab controller delegate.

Add the following to each view controller that needs to be the tab controller's delegate:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
}
```